# What happen to services when you update your app?

Tags: android, service

I have one service that I start in my Main Activity with

```
startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmService.class));
```

If I make change to the AlarmService class and then update my app, will the old service still be running when I start the new one?

I'm scared it create multiple services every time I update my app.

Comment: Please read [ask].